# Why would the following reaction not proceed through SN2 reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I made a guess that the OH- group cannot do a backside attack on the carbon because the C double bond with O and the 5 carbon ring may act as steric hindrance and prevent it from forming a bond but I'm not really sure.[image: organic chemistry reaction]

Comment: Carbonyls undergo addition-elimination. SN2 reactions at sp2-hybridized carbons are extremely rare (I only know of one report in the literature for a contrived case), so much so that you should never propose them.

Comment: Maybe it does. Take a look at this earlier SE Chem question, [Nucleophilic attack at a carbonyl - angle of attack](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39428/nucleophilic-attack-at-a-carbonyl-angle-of-attack/39432#39432).

Comment: when hydroxide ion attacks , there is a chance of negative electromeric effect at carbonyl group carbon atom, so backside attack is possible but backside to C double bond O

Answer (score 1):

The substrate in this reaction is an [Acyl Chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyl_chloride), which is highly susceptible to [nucleophilic acyl substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleophilic_acyl_substitution#), more so than other carboxylic acid derivatives, so SN2 attack (as mentioned in the comments) is highly improbable. The mechanism for this nucleophilic acyl substitution is as follows:

[image: mechanism]

With equilibrium constant $K_c >> 1$ favouring the products on the right.