# In the Wittig reaction, why do stabilised ylides produce E-alkenes and unstabilised ylides produce Z-alkenes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, stereochemistry, isomers

[image]

Wikipedia says that with unstabilised ylides they react very quickly in step 1-2 and step 4-5 is the rate limiting step. But with stabilised ylides step 1-2 is the rate limiting step and this is why stabilised ylides give E-alkenes. But there is no explanation as to why this makes E-alkenes and where in the mechanism it occurs.

I would have thought stabilised and unstabilised ylides would give E-alkenes to reduce steric hinderance but this is not the case. Any help explaining this would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: The Wittig reaction is generally considered to proceed via a concerted [2+2] cycloaddition, to form the oxaphosphetane **5** directly, without the intermediacy of the betaine **3**. Philipp's answer (based on thermodynamic oxaphosphetane formation) is a mechanism that was accepted and taught many years ago (Clayden 1st ed was published in 2002). Nowadays, the generally accepted explanation is different; please see the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have given some justification on why unstabilized ylids give Z-alkenes in [this answer of mine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5341/189).

A possible explanation why stabilized ylids show E-selectivity is given in the organic chemistry textbook by [Clayden, Warren, Wothers and Greeves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198503466) on p. 817:

[image]

Comment: Just a disclaimer: this explanation, given in Clayden et al. *Organic Chemistry* 1ed, is generally no longer considered to be correct. I've written up a summary of the experimental evidence and the currently accepted model for (E)-selectivity: [Why do stabilised ylids lead to trans alkenes in the Wittig reaction?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81763/16683)